# get child div content jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How do i get content of child DIV elements when the parent element is also a DIV. I want new line per child content. Here is the HTML i have.

```
<div id="Messages">
   <div class="MessageNew">This is test message </div><br>
   <div class="Message">Thank you ... </div><br>
   <div class="Message">Third test message. </div><br>
</div>
```

This is what i have tried

```
   var msgs = $("#Messages").text();
```

I am getting this output

```
This is test message Thank you ... Third test message.
```

This is what i want

```
This is test message 
Thank you ... 
Third test message.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#Messages div').each(function(index) {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

can also use - http://jsfiddle.net/TbS9z/

```
   $("#Messages div").each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Without taking into account your `<br>` elements, you could do this:

```
var msgs = "";
$("#Messages div").each(function() {
    msgs += $(this).text() + "\n";
});
alert(msgs);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/LWTrt/

This just goes through all the `div` elements within `#Messages` and adds them to a string with the new line delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a line break between each of them.

You could do something like

```
var msg = "";
$("Messages div").each(function(d) {
    msg += "\r\n" + $(this).text();
}
msg = msg.substring(2); //to remove the first "\r\n"
```

Alternately, you could check the length before adding a newline, and only do it if there is already text.

Of course, if you want to display this text elsewhere (like within another html element), you should replace the `\r\n` with `<br />`